# How do I save an NSString as a .txt file on my apps local documents directory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring

How do I save an NSString as a .txt file on my apps local documents directory (UTF-8)?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents directory

NSError *error;
BOOL succeed = [myString writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.txt"]
      atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (!succeed){
    // Handle error here
}
```

Comment: Don't pass `nil` for the `error:` argument. For one thing, it's the wrong type (`nil` is conceptually an `id`, whereas the `error:` argument is an `NSError **`, which is basically an `id *`); the constant of the proper type is `NULL`. More importantly, when this statement fails, don't you want to know why?

Comment: Progress, but you also should not assume that `error` is `nil` when the message succeeds. Test whether the message returned `YES` or `NO`, and only examine the error object when it returns `NO`. Citation: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-SW1 (first “important” sidebar—admittedly, it's a little oblique about it)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
NSString *homeDirectory;
homeDirectory = NSHomeDirectory(); // Get app's home directory - you could check for a folder here too.
BOOL isWriteable = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] isWritableFileAtPath: homeDirectory]; //Check file path is writealbe
// You can now add a file name to your path and the create the initial empty file

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:newFilePath contents:nil attributes:nil];

// Then as a you have an NSString you could simple use the writeFile: method
NSString *yourStringOfData;
[yourStringOfData writeToFile: newFilePath atomically: YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use NSUserDefaults

Saving:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject:@"TextToSave" forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
```

Reading:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *myString = [prefs stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
```

Comment: Agreed you could, and this is a valid alternative. Not what he's asking for but if you don't know how easy it is to use the prefs, you wouldn't know to use them. +1

Comment: Don't forget to call `[prefs synchronize]` after saving something to NSUserDefaults!

Answer (score 1):

He is how to save NSString into Documents folder. Saving other types of data can be also realized that way.

```
- (void)saveStringToDocuments:(NSString *)stringToSave {

 NSString *documentsFolder = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
 NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithString:@"savedString.txt"];

 NSString *path = [documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path contents:[stringToSave dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] attributes:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using this method to save some base64 encoded image data to the disk. When opening the text file on my computer I kept having trouble reading the data because of some line breaks and returns being added automatically.

The following code fixes this issue:

```
myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@""];

// write string to disk
```