# Create and save NSString data in to a file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i have 3`NSString` objects that i want to save to a new file when the app is running.

this will help me for remote debug!

if any one can help me creating the file and save the data to it will be very use full

thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save the files to the Documents directory, here is how to get the path to that directory:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
```

And a sample write statement:

```
NSError *error;
BOOL status = [string writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Answer (score 4):

In the [`NSString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) documentation there is method called `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:`.

```
NSError *error;
[@"Write me to file" writeToFile:@"<filepath>" atomically:YES encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents directory

NSError *error; BOOL succeed = [myString writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.txt"]
      atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
 if (!succeed){
        // Handle error here }
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184372/how-do-i-save-an-nsstring-as-a-txt-file-on-my-apps-local-documents-directory).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to save NSString into Documents folder. Saving other types of data can be also realized that way.

```
- (void)saveString:(NSString *)stringToSave toDocumentsWithFilename:(NSString *)fileName {

 NSString *documentsFolder = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *path = [documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path contents:[stringToSave dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] attributes:nil];

}
```

Usage:

```
NSString *stringWeWantToSave = @"This is an elephant";

NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithString:@"savedString.txt"];

[self saveString:stringWeWantToSave toDocumentsWithFilename:fileName];
```