# All I want to do is send a plaintext document to the iCloud from an iPhone.

Tags: objective-c, ios, icloud

I've been reading through questions and tutorials on this all day, but each of them seems much more complicated than is necessary for my implementation.

Goal: I want to take some system information from my app and package it into a simple report (like a .txt document). The user just clicks a button to send the timestamped document to their iCloud where they can view the file on their computer later. Each press of the button creates a new document for statistics at that moment in time. No downloading from the iCloud (on the phone) and No saving changes to/updating a single file.

From what I understand, UIDocument is the "middle-man" between the file and the cloud. However I have not been able to find something that could teach someone new to iOS/objective-c, like me, how to (1) Create a file from a string/NSString, and (2) Upload it to the iCloud from the phone.

I'm just trying to grasp the basics here and get a simple prototype working. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make a start with these links:

[Saving a .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184372/how-do-i-save-an-nsstring-as-a-txt-file-on-my-apps-local-documents-directory)

[icloud-and-uidocument-beyond-the-basics-part-1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12779/icloud-and-uidocument-beyond-the-basics-part-1)